# Running Next.js in production on HTTPS

Tags: next.js, https

I cannot figure out how to set my next js project to run on HTTPS.
I am using Next 12.3 and deploying on AWS EC2. I have my SSL sertificates and all ports are open. What should I do to run it like that?

P.S.

All the answers that I've found are about running on HTTPS during the development.
Some people even claimed that it is not natively supported by Next. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup `nginx`, this becomes extremely easy.

You can handle the SSL part in `nginx` and run your NextJS server normally and you will have a server running on HTTPS.

See [Configuring HTTPS servers](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for setting up Nginx.

Comment: Thanks! I found it to be the cheapest option. For the future seekers like me: https://medium.com/today-i-solved/how-to-deploy-next-js-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-https-7980ec6fe8d3

Comment: This really does not answer the question well at all.